# Typescript export funtion can not return value

Tags: typescript

There is 2 ts file like as this:

kiv_handler.ts

```
export let a: any = 1
export function get(key: any) {
    const {con} = require('../src/utils/mysql')
    con.query(`select * from kiv_def where s_key = '${key}'`, (err, rsl) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
            return
        }
        if(rsl) {
            console.log(rsl[0].s_value)
            return rsl[0].s_value;
        }
        else return        
    })
}
```

and test.ts

```
import * as kiv from "../../handlers/kiv_handler"
console.log(`rKey3: ${kiv.get('abc')} ${kiv.a}`)
```

But when I run it and got result

```
rKey3: undefined 1
1
```

I don't know why my function "get" can not return value. And the log write test.ts before kiv_handler.ts.

Answer (score 0):

Your `return` statements are returning from the arrow function, not the outer `get` function. Because the `query` call takes a callback, you can assume that it is asynchronous; `get` will return before the `query` is done. You'll need `get` to likewise take a callback or return a Promise, so your code can process the resulting value *after* it returns.